Mysql syntax error using php exec shell commands regarding version of mysql
hello am always getting mysql syntax error , check the version etc ..
$databaseName = sprintf("%s_%s", substr($this->user, 0, 8), $installationData['worldId']);
        // Create database with $databaseName $dbPassword
        echo shell_exec("mysql -u root -p'testkmc123' -e \"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$databaseName`\"");
        echo shell_exec("mysql -u root -p'testkmc123' -e \"CREATE USER {$databaseName} IDENTIFIED BY '{$dbPassword}'\"");
        echo shell_exec("mysql -u root -p'testkmc123' -e \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {$databaseName}.* TO {$databaseName}\"");

can any one tell me what am i doing wrong ?
i tried everything without hope
errors am getting
 mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Jul 29 17:04:44 alma-vps.local runTasks.php[109697]: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to us>
Jul 29 17:04:44 alma-vps.local runTasks.php[109698]: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Jul 29 17:04:44 alma-vps.local runTasks.php[109698]: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to us>
Jul 29 17:04:44 alma-vps.local runTasks.php[109699]: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Jul 29 17:04:44 alma-vps.local runTasks.php[109699]: ERROR 1064 

am doing it using shell_exec because of something its a huge script am working on , i just need to see why its giving syntax errors for this 3 queries

Why are you using the shell to perform mysql queries instead of using PHP's built-in mysqli or PDO libraries?

Which query is getting the error? Please post the full error message

all of them having syntax error
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Jul 29 17:04:44 alma-vps.local runTasks.php[109697]: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to us>

i have to use shell for some reasons

There isn't more to that line? It looks like the line is being truncated to being too long and word wrap isn't turned on in your console/editor. If you're using an editor, go to that line and try to move right to the end.

If someone asks you "why" then "some reasons" isn't an explanation. It would be interesting to know what those reasons are, in case there's actually a more sensible approach. When people ask you that kind of thing, it's because it would be useful information, not just idle curiosity.

Its a complicated browser game and this script is running by ssh

this script...you mean the PHP script? Well that doesn't prevent you from using PDO or mysqli, as far as I can tell. Did you try to use one of them? What specifically was the problem? And the browser bit is surely irrelevant? PHP doesn't run in the browser. If you don't mean the PHP script, then clarify what you do mean. Always be specific with your descriptions. You are doing something which is strange and unusual and making your code more complicated because of it - in 99% of cases we find that people do that because of some misunderstanding, rather than because it's really necessary.

Try redirecting stderr so you see the full error message. Add 2>&1 to the end of the command lines.
